# How do you find vertical and horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus

Whenever i am doing curve sketching in calculus class i find it incredibly  difficult to find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes and as such i always get up to that point correct and anything from asymptotes  and further wrong. Sometimes even my curve is a bit off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine your question only pertains to rational functions.

For vertical asymptotes, these occur when there is an $x$ in the denominator. Set the denominator equal to zero and solve for $x$ to find the vertical asymptotes.

For horizontal asymptotes, if the denominator is of higher degree than the numerator, there exists a horizontal asymptote at $f(x)=0$. If the degree of the numerator and denominator are the same, then the asymptote occurs at $f(x)=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ is the leading coefficient of the numerator and $b$ is the leading coefficient of the denominator. If the degree of the numerator is greater than that of the denominator, no horizontal asymptotes exist.

Answer (score 0):

if your curve is of the form $y = f(x)$

1) For horizontal asymptotes, set ${x\to \pm\infty}$

2) For vertical asymptotes, set ${x\to \pm0}$